Not sure about my Jira Smart Value Conditional Logic Syntax
Here is what I'm currently using that only works when the first through third "if" is true, but fails to output the value when the fourth "if" is true.
Device Name: {{#if(not(lookupObjects.Device Name.isEmpty))}}*{{lookupObjects.Device Name}}* > {{/}}{{#if(lookupObjects.Device Name.isEmpty)}}_none_ > {{/}}{{#if(not(issue.customfield_10393.value.isEmpty))}}{{customfield_10393}}{{#if(issue.customfield_10393.value.isBlank)}}_none_{{/}}{{/}}

The output I get when either the first or second "if" is true, the third "if" is false, and the fourth "if" is true is as follows:
Device Name: someValue > **
The "**" should be surrounding the value of the third "if" ONLY when it's true, and I don't get the value that's supposed to print when the fourth "if" is true.
I don't know if this is a limitation of Jira or just bad syntax.

I've tried using ".isEmpty"
I've tried using ".isNotEmpty"
I found documentation showing another way I could achieve the desired result:
{{if(smartValue, "value if true", "value if false")}}

However, there's no example on the page (Automation smart values - conditional logic). Here is what I've tried:
Asset Tag: {{#if(lookupObjects.Asset Tag.isNotEmpty, "lookupObjects.Asset Tag.value", "_none_")}}{{/}} > {{#if(issue.customfield_11607.isNotEmpty, "customfield_11607.value", "_none_")}}{{/}}

If I surround the "lookupObjects.Asset Tag.value" with curly brackets, I get an error saying the string needs to be closed. I've tried just putting "TRUE" and "FALSE" as what prints out when the "lookupObjects.Asset Tag.isNotEmpty" is true or false. I've tried with ".isEmpty" as well, but nothing ever prints out.

I wasn't able to figure out the syntax of the alternate route I was trying, but I did find a solution to my initial problem:
Device Name: {{#if(not(lookupObjects.Device Name.isEmpty))}}*{{lookupObjects.Device Name}}*{{/}}{{#if(lookupObjects.Device Name.isEmpty)}}_none_{{/}} > {{#if(equals(customfield_10393, isEmpty))}}_none_{{/}}{{#if(issue.Device Name.isNotEmpty)}}*{{customfield_10393}}*{{/}}

I don't know why it works this way, but it works. I don't question the code gods. I just accept their blessing. lol
